# scrape webpage bypass server error

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to scrape below webpage

```
parenturl = http://www.liberty.co.uk/fcp/product/Liberty//Rosa-A-Tana-Lawn/1390
```

but I get below error

```
srcpage = getURLContent(GET(parenturl)$url,timeout(10))
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Empty reply from server
```

Is it possible to bypass and scrape webpage

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: Why did you use `timeout`?  I can read this url with `readLines`, but it doesn't format the html part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `httr` library instead:

```
library(httr)

pg <- GET("http://www.liberty.co.uk/fcp/product/Liberty//Rosa-A-Tana-Lawn/1390")
print(content(pg))
# too much to paste here
```